Django 5.x: directory /workspace/staticfiles does not exist
I am trying to deploy an application in DO App platform and everything worked as expected. As a more stable media and static files handling I am trying to implement DO spaces to store static and media files. Here is how my settings look like for that:
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN', 'your_access_key_id')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'your_access_key_id')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'your_secret_access_key')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', 'bucket_name')
AWS_REGION = os.environ.get('AWS_REGION', 'region')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "access_key": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            "secret_key": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            "endpoint_url": AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
            "region_name": AWS_REGION,
            "default_acl": 'public-read',
            "querystring_auth": False,
        },
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3StaticStorage",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "access_key": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            "secret_key": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            "endpoint_url": AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
            "region_name": AWS_REGION,
        },
    },
}
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.{AWS_REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.{AWS_REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

But When I deploy it I keep getting: directory /workspace/staticfiles does not exist
How do I solve it?
Thanks
I went to digital oceans deployment guides and also searched through stackoverflow and reddit but no luck.

Neither workspace nor staticfiles exist as a path component in the config you gave us. Make sure your example the reproducible for us.

As I said I am using DO app platform. I think workspace is their internal path. At least I didn't define it anywhere in my knowledge.

Still you have to give us a minimal reproducible example. You might have to reduce your config to the minimal part that produces the given problem without needing to be run in your environment.

Its simple django application. I installed boto3 and django-storages. Added storages to installed app. And then I am using above settings. All I am trying to do is deploy it on digital ocean app platform with DO spaces support for static and media files.

its too broad.. have you tried to read "how to manage static files" guide in django documentation?
